# is onActivityResult fundamentally broken?

Tags: android, deprecated, onactivityresult, startactivityforresult

Some implementations of it, as well as seemingly some devices, seemingly never return RESULT_OK which equals -1, and just return a misleading 0 while including all the necessary data in the Intent extras

I've seen a lot of Google example code simply not do a condition on the resultCode anymore, but they can deprecate it without breaking anything, given Google's propensity to deprecate completely non functional methods because they like their new name more, they could overload a new onActivityResult to simply not have the resultCode as a method parameter.

I was wondering if there is a technical explanation or a blog post for what that particular message passing protocol has seemed to simply fail, without any update in the documentation saying "hey maybe *don't* rely on the resultCode following any rhyme or reason"

Comment: Why is a 0 misleading? It is `RESULT_CANCELED`

Comment: "Some implementations of it, as well as seemingly some devices, seemingly never return RESULT_OK which equals -1, and just return a misleading 0" -- presumably, the app that you started did not call `setResult()`, or called `setResult()` with `RESULT_CANCELED`. Do you have any evidence to the contrary? "I've seen a lot of Google example code simply not do a condition on the resultCode anymore" -- links, or it didn't happen. :-)

Comment: @CommonsWare well best example (not the one I'm experiencing today) is that I've seen Camera and Gallery intents function as expected and still return result cancelled, yet still have a URI and properly created file and everything the request needed to continue, while still setting requestCode cancelled

Comment: If by "Camera... intents", you mean `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`, camera apps aren't supposed to return a `Uri`. Beyond that, "Camera and Gallery intents", assuming that you mean things like `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` and `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`, are handled by apps, whether supplied by the device manufacturer, third parties, or Google. The fact that some of those apps may have bugs does not indicate that `onActivityResult()` has bugs.

Answer (score 4):

The result code value is a contract defined by the specific activity's implementation. The only contract defined by Android proper is that the result code is an integer.

Android defined simple constants for success (`RESULT_OK`) and fail (`RESULT_CANCEL`), but it's up to the activity to decide if it wants to use those, for what purpose, to use different values, or to not even set a result code (in which case the default is `RESULT_CANCEL`). In many cases, a simple success or fail isn't complete enough and activities return other int values.

So, the short answer is you need to consult the source of the activity to see what it does (or the documentation, but the contract is unlikely to be defined there).